# How to get Get a C# Enumeration in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, enumeration

I have an `enum` in my C# code and I want to get the same `enum` in javascript.

Is there any way to do this without hardcoding?

Comment: I have an answer to that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8345355/share-enums-between-c-sharp-and-javascript-in-mvc-razor/13297288#13297288 but using MVC/Razor though.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can serialize all enum values to JSON:

```
private void ExportEnum<T>()
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    var values = Enum.GetValues(type).Cast<T>();
    var dict = values.ToDictionary(e => e.ToString(), e => Convert.ToInt32(e));
    var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(dict);
    var script = string.Format("{0}={1};", type.Name, json);
    System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "CloseLightbox", script, true);
}

ExportEnum<MyEnum>();
```

This registers a script like:

```
MyEnum={"Red":1,"Green":2,"Blue":3};
```

Comment: I realize this is a nearly three-year-old answer, but nonetheless, major props for what I think is a really elegant solution to this problem.

Answer (score 7):

If you want it as viewmodel -> view -> JS

Requires:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
```

Viewmodel:

```
// viewmodel property:
 public string MyEumJson
        {
            get
            {
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEum)), new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter());
            }
        }
```

Then in your .cshtml:

```
@* View *@

<script>
    var myEnumInJS = '@Html.Raw(Model.MyEumJson)';
</script>
```

this will be evaluated as

[image]

Comment: and how to user it

Comment: @BasheerAL-MOMANI  I had the same question, try like this: `var text = myEnumInJS[1]'`

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can do it like this, i did it like this:

```
    var OrderStateId = parseInt(stateVal);

    if (OrderStateId === @((int)OrderStates.Approved)) {
        // 5 is the Approved state
        if (OrderOption === "Quote") {
        $('#quoteDiv').css('display', 'block');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it to a list and then serialise it to JSON, for example:

```
// In the code-behind
private void _Default_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var objects = GetObjects();

    var serialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    this.MyHiddenField.Value = serialiser.Serialize(objects);
}

// Example enumerable
static IEnumerable<MyClass> GetObjects()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        yield return new MyClass();
    }
}
```

The above requires .Net 3.5 and a reference to the `System.Web.Extensions` assembly (for the use of `JavaScriptSerializer`, however alternative JSON serialisation libraries exist for .Net.

In your javascript code you should use a JSON serialisation library (such as [json2](http://www.json.org/js.html)) to deserialise your list:

```
var mylist = JSON.parse($("#MyHiddenField").val());
for (var i in mylist)
{
     var item = mylist[i];
}
```

**Update:** Agg, I promise to actually *read* the question next time - **enumeration**, not **enumerable**!

Answer (score 1):

**For Razor**

Works perfectly for Razor like this

```
var Enumerators = {
   System: {
           @{
               <text>DayOfWeek: JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek)), new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter()))')</text>
           }
    }
}
```

---

This would give result like this in javaScript

```
Enumerators.System.DayOfWeek = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"]
```

Please let me know if there is a mistake or not accordingly fitting to the required need, Thank You

**For C# Server Side**

Please see the following answer that might be useful

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29184357/6737444

Answer (score 0):

Here is the post that answered your question:

[JSON serialization of enum as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441290/json-serialization-of-c-enum-as-string)

Answer (score -2):

I found a good solution here

http://fairwaytech.com/2014/03/making-c-enums-available-within-javascript/

The only problem I have is that it doesn't carry the `Description` attributes. If you don't use/need descriptions then it is perfect.

This provides you with access on the client side, like so:

```
var Enums = { 
    phoneType: {phone:1,fax:2,voiceMail:3,cell:4,},
    addressType: {mailing:1,physical:2,} 
    };
```