# Serializing a class as a single JSON string in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-3, serialization

I have the following class

```
[Serializable]
public class ApiRequestStatus :IEquatable<ApiRequestStatus>
{
    public static readonly ApiRequestStatus Failure =
                                            new ApiRequestStatus("Failure");
    public static readonly ApiRequestStatus Success =
                                            new ApiRequestStatus("Success");

    private string _status;

    private ApiRequestStatus(string status)
    {
        this._status = status;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _status;
    }

    public bool Equals(ApiRequestStatus other)
    {
        return this._status == other._status;
    }
}
```

When this is serialized using the [`System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) I'd like it to serialize as the string `"Failure"` or `"Success"`.

I've tried implementing a custom `JavaScriptConverter` but this renders my object as an object with zero or more properties depending on the `IDictionary<string, object>` I return.

e.g. When I return and empty `IDictionary<string, object>` my object appear as an empty JavaScript object : `{ }`.

If I return `new Dictionary<string, object> { {"_status", status._status}}` my object appears as `{ "_status" : "Success" }`.

**How can I serialize the object just as the string value of it's `_status` field?**

Comment: can't say if it works but you could try with "public static implicit operator string(ApiRequestStatus apiRs) { return apiRs._status }". this should at least enable you to do "string s = apiRequestStatusObj;" and  the "s" should then contain the status. (the implicit operator should be in you class)

Comment: @Joakim that hasn't had any effect unfortunately. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Add a `ToJsonString()` method to your class, and control your serialization manually - in this case serialize the `_status` member directly.

For all other / default behaviour, just serialize `this` (this can be inherited for tidiness) and return it.

Comment: Unfortunately the `ApiRequestStatus` object is part of a much larger top-level object which is being serialized using the `JavaScriptSerializer` so I can't get granular control of each object individually.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by switching my `ApiRequestStatus` to an enum and using the [`Json.NET`](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) serializer in conjunction with the [`JsonConverter` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441290/json-serialization-of-c-sharp-enum-as-string#2870420) but I'd still be interested to see if this is possible with the `JavaScriptSerializer`.