# How do I serialize an enum value as a string?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-3, serialization

I'm using .net's JavaScriptSerializer and when serializing an object, enums are serialized as their int value instead of their string name, which kind of defeats the purpose of an enum. How do I get it to serialize all enums to their string name instead? Can I accomplish this with the built-in serializer, or is there a better one I should be using?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There's some good answers (alternatives) and discussions here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441290/json-serialization-of-c-sharp-enum-as-string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Newtonsoft's JsonNet serializer has this functionality built in with an enum converter.

Download it here: http://json.codeplex.com/

`using Newtonsoft.Json;`

`using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;`

```
var objToSerialize = new Object();

var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());

var serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(settings);

var sb = new StringBuilder();
using (var sw = new StringWriter(sb))
{
    serializer.Serialize(sw, objToSerialize);
}

string json = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use the Value property of the EnumMemberAttribute attribute, as following example from MSDN.

```
[DataContract(Name = "CarCondition")]
public enum CarConditionWithDifferentNames
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "New")]
    BrandNew,
    [EnumMember(Value = "Used")]
    PreviouslyOwned,
    [EnumMember]
    Rental
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As seen in a number of other post, the .NET JsonSerializer or DataContractJsonSerializer don't respect the EnumMember attribute, but use the numeric value for the different members of the enumeration.

So writing your own custom serializer or use some 3rd party libraries are the way forward.