# Applying a global converter to Json.NET

Tags: c#, json.net

Let's say I have an example class:

```
public class SomeObject
{
    private FlagEnumerable _someFlagValue = FlagEnumerable.Flag1;

    public SomeObject()
    {
    }

    [DataMember(Name = "someFlagValue")]
    [Browsable(false)]
    public FlagEnumerable SomeFlagValue
    {
        get { return _someFlagValue; }
        set { _someFlagValue= value; }
    }
}
```

And this is how I describe my `FlagEnumerable`:

```
[DataContract]
[Flags]
[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonEnumConverter))]
public enum FlagEnumerable
{
    [EnumMember]
    Flag1 = 1,

    [EnumMember]
    Flag2 = 2,

    [EnumMember]
    Flag3 = 4
}
```

Additionally, I have a custom JSON converter that converts my enums to strings, flag enums to the arrays of strings, and vice versa.

This code works good, and successfully deserializing example JSON:

```
{
    someFlagValue: [
        "Flag1"
    ]
}
```

The question is how to apply a global converter to the JsonSerializer? When I remove `[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonEnumConverter))]` from `FlagEnumerable` and then add it by calling

```
MyJsonSerializer.Converters.Add(new JsonEnumConverter());
```

I'm getting this error:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'FlagEnumerable' because the type requires a JSON primitive value (e.g. string, number, boolean, null) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON primitive value (e.g. string, number, boolean, null) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.

Any help is appreciated! Sorry if not clear, feel free to ask questions.

Comment: Hey, did you ever figure out how to achieve this? I'm looking for exactly the same thing (I don't want to decorate All of my enums, and prefer doing it globally)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same need to serialize flags enumerable as a string array. I think something has changed since the time you posted the question.
I'm currently able to achieve this by using the following converter:

```
[Flags]
enum FlagEnumerable
{
    Flag1 = 1,
    Flag2 = 2,
    Flag3 = 4
}

class FlagsEnumConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType.IsEnum && objectType.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(FlagsAttribute), false).Any();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var values = serializer.Deserialize<string[]>(reader);

        return values
            .Select(x => Enum.Parse(objectType, x))
            .Aggregate(0, (current, value) => current | (int) value);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var enumArr = Enum.GetValues(value.GetType())
            .Cast<int>()
            .Where(x => (x & (int) value) == x)
            .Select(x => Enum.ToObject(value.GetType(), x).ToString())
            .ToArray();

        serializer.Serialize(writer, enumArr);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
            Converters = new List<JsonConverter>() {new FlagsEnumConverter()}
        };

        var targetObj = new { MyField = FlagEnumerable.Flag1 | FlagEnumerable.Flag3 };
        var str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(targetObj);
        var deserializedObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(str, targetObj.GetType());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the top-rated answer to this question: [JSON serialization of enum as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441290/json-serialization-of-c-sharp-enum-as-string) what you need is the `StringEnumConverter`.

Using it, this code:

```
SomeObject someObject = new SomeObject() { SomeFlagValue = FlagEnumerable.Flag3 };
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(someObject,
    Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented,
    new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter());
```

Will produce this JSON:

```
{
    "SomeFlagValue": "Flag3"
}
```

Note that it doesn't appear to be neccessary to pass in a `StringEnumConverter` when deserializing - that block of JSON above could be deserialized just fine.