# How do you serialize an enum array to a Json array of strings?

Tags: javascript, json.net, javascriptserializer

Based on Diego's unanswered comment under the top-voted answer in this question:

[JSON serialization of enum as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441290/json-serialization-of-c-sharp-enum-as-string)

So for an enum:

```
public enum ContactType
{
    Phone = 0,
    Email = 1,
    Mobile = 2
}
```

And for eg. a property:

```
//could contain ContactType.Phone, ContactType.Email, ContactType.Mobile
IEnumerable<ContactType> AvailableContactTypes {get;set;}
```

To something like the JSON:

```
{ContactTypes : ['Phone','Email','Mobile']}
```

instead of

```
{ContactTypes : [0,1,2]}
```

As is the case with the normal JavaScriptSerializer?

Comment: Use strings for the values?

Comment: Some serialization libraries have a boolean that you can flip to determine the output of a serialized enumeration.  I seen a video of one of the MVC developers that demoed the feature..unfortunately I couldn't hunt down the video.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear that in one of the later versions of Json.NET there is proper provision for this, via the [`ItemConverterType`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_ItemConverterType.htm) property of the [`JsonProperty`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) attribute, as documented here:

http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2012/05/08/json-net-4-5-release-5-jsonproperty-enhancements.aspx

I was unable to try it out as I hit problems upgrading from Json.NET 3.5 that were related to my own project. In the end I converted my viewmodel to `IEnumerable<string>` as per Shmiddty's suggestion (there is still an impedance mismatch though and I will come back to refactor this in future).

Hope that helps anyone else with the same problem!

Example usage:

```
[JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
IEnumerable<ContactType> AvailableContactTypes {get;set;}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've always found it easier to add an additional property in these cases than to try to change the behavior of the json.net parser.

```
[JsonIgnore]
IEnumerable<ContactType> AvailableContactTypes {get;set;}

IEnumerable<string> AvailableContactTypesString
{
    get { return AvailableContactTypes.Select(c => c.ToString()); }
}
```

Of course, if you need to deserialize, you'd need a setter on that property as well.

```
set { AvailableContactTypes = value
    .Select(c => Enum.Parse(typeof(ContactType), c) as ContactType); }
```

Comment: Yeah, currently doing that but not as a property, just in the constructor...bit crufty though...

Comment: Could not get it to work