# C# JSON convert enums to/from strings

Tags: c#, json, enums, asp.net-web-api

There is a question about [generically converting enums to/from strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-enum-in-c). This questions is a little different.

Is there a way in an ASP.NET Web API 2 app to define the controller API for a call where it will receive/return JSON where the property is a string in the JSON, but it is declared as an enum?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON serialization of c# enum as string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441290/json-serialization-of-c-sharp-enum-as-string)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JSON.NET, you can use the following attribute for your Enum object-

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
```

Check this [link](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_StringEnumConverter.htm).