# JSON StringEnumConverter Not Working

Tags: c#, json, enums

I have a class contains an enum property and using newtonsoft.json serilaizer  I am serializing an instance of it .
I want the output of serializing this property to be the string value of the property,so I used *StringEnumConverter*
but the output was like this

** without converter :
    "FailOrPassProperty":**1**

** with converter :
    "FailOrPassProperty":**"1"**

So using the converter it seems like it is getting the ToString() of the integer

I have tried this solution but it didn't work:
[JSON serialization of enum as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441290/json-serialization-of-enum-as-string)

Note: I cannot use attribute decoration due to business rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this out :

```
[TestClass]
public class JsonStringTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void EnumToStringSerializationTest()
    {
        var testMe = new TestMe()
        {
            UserType = UserType.User,
        };
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        settings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
        var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testMe, settings);
        Assert.AreEqual(jsonString, "{\"UserType\":\"User\"}");
    }
}



public class TestMe
{
    public UserType UserType { get; set; }
}



public enum UserType
{
    Admin = 1,
    User = 2
}
```

---

**Update :**

**Just wanted to add this note :**
make sure that your enum items doesn't have `EnumMember` Attribute because the `StringEnumConverter` will use this value instead of the enum item name.

[for more information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.enummemberattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)