# How to convert the jsonconverter type from integer enum values in asp.net using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums

I am using enum for dayofweek. We go to asp builder and model page,to apply jsond property,default values,and jsonconverter. Here what do i apply for `jsonconverter(typeof(..?))`
But we are using string type in enum values we are used stringenumconverter. please reply.

```
public enum dayofweek{
sunday = 0,
monday = 1,
.
.
saturday = 6
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for

```
 [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
```

checkout more info on other so answer [JSON serialization of enum as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441290/json-serialization-of-enum-as-string)