# How to get enum as an json object

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, enums

I have this enum

```
public enum ComplainStatus
{           
    Started = 1,    
    Ended = 2,
    Canceled = 3    
}
```

I need to fill DDL in javascript 
So I make a Webmethod
as

```
[WebMethod]
public static string getComplainstatus()
{            
    JavaScriptSerializer TheSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string TheJson = TheSerializer.Serialize(ComplainStatus);
    return TheJson;
}
```

I need to get the enum as an object that can enable me to read it in JS file

Comment: Are you using WCF?

Answer (score 0):

Please see answer in this question: [JSON serialization of enum as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441290/json-serialization-of-enum-as-string?rq=1)

Quote:

> I have found that Json.NET provides the exact functionality I'm
>   looking for with a StringEnumConverter attribute:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public Gender Gender {get; set;}
```

> More details at available on [StringEnumConverter documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_StringEnumConverter.htm).