# ASP.NET MVC showing text from Enum column in jquery DataTables?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, enums, datatables

How should I show text from a enum column instead of its value in a jQuery DataTable, without losing its value as I'll be using it later for editing purposes?

Given a **Class**:

```
 public class Person
    {
        [Key]
        public int PersonUID { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public EstadoPersona Status { get; set; }
}
```

And a **Enum**:

```
 public enum EstadoPersona
    {
        Active, Inactive
    }
```

I'm populating a jQuery DataTable using the following action from **Controller**:

```
  public ActionResult List()
        {
            var data = db.People.Select(
               a => new
               {
                   a.FirstName,
                   a.Status,
                   a.PersonUID
               }).OrderByDescending(a => a.PersonUID).ToList();

            return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

And this is my **DataTable** set up:

```
$("#tblPersons").DataTable({
                processing: true,
                dom: 'Brtip',
                ajax: {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/People/List",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: function (data) {
                        return data = JSON.stringify(data);
                    },
                    dataSrc: "",
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        debugger; alert("ajax error: " + textStatus);
                    }
                },
                columns: [
                   {data: "FirstName" },
                   { data: "Status"},
                   { data: "PersonUID" }
                ],
                rowId: 'PersonUID',
                },
                order: [],
            });
```

Comment: so you're trying to use the jquery datatable plugin? Please change your question's tag. `datatable` is ambiguous

Comment: Yes, indeed... I'm using jQuery DataTables. I'm trying to change the tag related but it won't persist after clicking save.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:** I wrote this whole answer saying you couldn't then found out a way to do it in the question I linked to show that you couldn't (d'oh), using the JSON.NET extension. See the **Edit** if you are willing to use that extension (it's pretty great).

**Original Answer**

See [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441290/json-serialization-of-enum-as-string) (quoted the important answer below)

> `JavaScriptSerializer` [what is used when you convert the data to JSON] serializes `enums` to their numeric values and not their `string` representation. You would need to use custom serialization to serialize the enum as its name instead of numeric value.

Unfortunately, when you convert the `enum` to JSON, it has been converted to an `int` and the `enum` status has been lost.

This means that you can't simply send the string (and that wouldn't be good enough for you anyway, since you want to have both the string value and the numeric value).

What I'd recommend doing is changing the object that is sent to DataTables to be a `KeyValuePair<string,int>`. Now, this isn't a perfect solution, since you'll have to convert from the `enum` to the `KeyValuePair` both before you send and after you receive the data, but it's probably the simplest way to keep the string name and numeric value attached to each other when they're used in the JavaScript.

Basically, you'll have to modify your creation of the objects sent to DataTables so that instead of just adding `a.status` you can instead in that object creation, create the key-value pair.

While this isn't really what you wanted, it is an unfortunate fact that you can't serialize an `enum` into JSON and keep the name, only the value. You'll have to either convert the `enum` into another type that can hold two values (`KeyValuePair`, an array, a `Dictionary`, whatever) during the serialization process or just stop using an enum.

**Edit:** Upon looking further into the linked question, it looks like if you use the JSON.NET extension, you actually can serialize enums. If you're willing to use that extension, that could be a very nice solution to your problem. I've used it before, and it's pretty useful and not difficult to use.

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
```

Is the syntax you'd use if you use JSON.NET. You can get some more detail in the second answer on the question I linked.

**Edit 2:** After seeing Vijai's answer (which shows a nice example of how you would actually add the above attribute to *your* class), it appears that this will only send the string name of the `enum`, not both the name and the value. You may still have to send an object other than an `enum`, as in my original answer, if you want both the string and int values.

Answer (score 4):

Use Json.Net http://www.newtonsoft.com/json and decorate following attribute for the Enum type column

```
public class Person
    {
        [Key]
        public int PersonUID { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
        public EstadoPersona Status { get; set; }
}
```

to post the values as `{"Status":"Active"}` or `{"Status":"InActive"}` instead of  `{"Status":0}` or `{"Status":1}`