# Using JsonConverter for enum element value

Tags: c#, json, converters

After reading this post [JSON serialization of enum as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441290/json-serialization-of-enum-as-string) I'm still searching for a quick way to use into Razor javascript this type of Enum:

```
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public enum StatusReplacement
    {
        ApprovalPending = 1,
        Canceled = 2,
        Approved = 3,
        AwaitingDelivery = 4,
        Delivered = 5,
        Completed = 6
    }
```

By using JsonConverter **I just can take the element enums but not their values**. I also tried unsuccessfully to set over each element [EnumMember(Value = "")].

Expected result

```
...Razor...
<script>
var elementValue = @StatusReplacement.ApprovalPending;
alert(elementValue) //Expecting to return 1 instead of ApprovalPending *undefined.
</script>
```

I'm not sure yet if I really have use any king of html helper for this purpose. 
I suspicious there is an easier way to achieve it today working with MVC 4+.

Regards,
Rubens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON formatter takes preference on the output of the data and provides a string output of the enum value itself:

```
var data = "@StatusReplacement.ApprovalPending"; // = ApprovalPending
```

You should use

```
var data = @((int)StatusReplacement.ApprovalPending); // = 1
```

to explicitly use the `int` value.

Comment: That's what I was exactly looking for. Many thanks @stephen-reindl

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of things you can do.

```
var elementValue = @Json.Encode(StatusReplacement.ApprovalPending);
```

There will be a *little* more overhead to doing `Json.Encode` however, if you you're using custom values (e.g. changing the Json value of `ApprovalPending` to be `foo`) then this is your best option.

Or, if you don't plan on doing custom values, you can just do `ToString()`

```
var elementValue = @StatusReplacement.ApprovalPending.ToString();
```

Comment: Great approach @cameron specially cus you considered the possibility to change enum element members descriptions. Your contribution was very useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is probably to just cast your enum value into an int in your Razor code:

```
var elementValue = @((int)StatusReplacement.ApprovalPending);
```

It's a bit clumsy but does the work. 
Alternatively you could add an extension method that returns the int value:

Add the following method to a static class:

```
public static int EnumValue(this StatusReplacement statusReplacement) 
{
   return (int)statusReplacement;
}
```

This can then be called from your razor code:

```
var elementValue = @StatusReplacement.ApprovalPending.EnumValue();
```

Comment: You are right @rune-grimstad I guess the easiest solution is cast enum. However, the other solutions you've suggested are very welcome and also easy to use. Thank you.