# Change status value from int to string

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, enums, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a status property with `int` values in array of objects. Below is the output of array of objects.

```
[
    {
        "enterpriseServiceId": 1,
        "enterpriseServices": {},
        "status": 3,
        "id": 1,
        "createdOn": "2017-12-29T17:58:15.4855946",
        "createdBy": "System",
        "modifiedOn": "2017-12-29T17:58:15.4855946",
        "modifiedBy": "System"
    },
    {
        "enterpriseServiceId": 2,
        "enterpriseServices": {},
        "status": 1,
        "id": 2,
        "createdOn": "2017-12-29T17:58:15.4855946",
        "createdBy": "System",
        "modifiedOn": "2017-12-29T17:58:15.4855946",
        "modifiedBy": "System"
    }
]
```

The `status` property is enum value type. I am trying to convert that to string value so it is easier to read when it is returned in output.

Below is my code that gets the data from sql server database.

**ENUM**

```
namespace CoreLibrary.Models.Enums
{
    public static class Common
    {
        public enum Status
        {


    Active = 1,
        InActive,
        Completed,
        Failed,
        InProgress,
        Pause,
        Resume,
        Skip,
        Running
    }
}
```

}

**Entity Model:**

```
namespace CoreLibrary.Models.Entities
{
    public class Deployments : BaseProperties
    {
        public int EnterpriseServiceId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("EnterpriseServiceId")]
        public virtual EnterpriseServices EnterpriseServices { get; set; }
        public Common.Status Status { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Method that retrieves data from database:**

```
[HttpGet("~/api/Deployments/GetWithJoins")]
public JsonResult GetWithJoins()
{
    try
    {
        // includeList for including data from external tables (JOIN Query)
        var includeList = new List<Expression<Func<Deployments, object>>>();
        includeList.Add(d => d.EnterpriseServices);

        IEnumerable<Deployments> result = _repository.GetByIdWithJoins(queryable: includeList).ToList();
        return Json(result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var innerException = ex.InnerException == null ? null : ex.InnerException.Message.ToString();
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        return Json(new { status = "failed", message = ex.Message.ToString(), innerException = innerException });
    }
}
```

The result variable returns the output I shared at very beginning of this post. I am trying to convert `status` to return `string` value instead of `int`.

I am not sure if thats even possible or it is the right way to output of `status` int to string value?

I tried online, but I havent found a solution to my requirement. I would appreciate any help you guys can give. :)

Comment: You could simply cast an int to an enum? As already discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29482/cast-int-to-enum-in-c-sharp

Comment: hmm that one is more of a single int to string. How do I convert array of object without iterating over each object to update `status`?

Comment: Is your class Deployments internally generated?

Comment: well its a class that I created for model. I hope that answers the question?

Comment: You could simply have a string property: `public string StatusText { get { return Status.ToString(); } }` in that class

Comment: Thanks Tony. That's also a good suggestion.

Comment: I removed my duplicate flag because I think I pointed at the wrong post. It should actually be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441290/json-serialization-of-enum-as-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we call [`JSON(someObject)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.json(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Controller.Json(System.Object)), ASP.NET uses its [`JavaScriptSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) to create a [`JsonResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult(v=vs.118).aspx). The default configuration of the `JavaScriptSerializer` converts enums to their integer representation.

We can configure the serializer to use a string representation of enums instead. There are details on how to do that here: [JSON serialization of enum as string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2441290/1108891)

If that approach does not appeal, then you can use LINQ to map to an anonymous object using [`Enum.ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/16c1xs4z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). [Here is an example:](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PJtusk)

```
var result = deployments.Select(x =>
{
    return new 
    {
        Status = x.Status.ToString(),
        x.EnterpriseServiceId
    };
});
```

While the LINQ approach will work, it might lead to maintenance problems in the long-term.

Comment: first approach worked very well. I was able to retrieve json with string value for `status`. Also thanks for the alternative option.