# How to submit Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table.TableEntitity with an enum field?

Tags: azure, serialization, enums, azure-cosmosdb

I'm sending a Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table.TableEntity with an enum field and when it makes to cosmosdb the enum field has been dropped. So I think this happens because it's not a native type and serialization is messing up.

What is the right way of doing this?

Do I need to override ReadEntity and WriteEntity or is there any other way?
I'm thinking there ought to be something like Newtonsoft's

[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))] attribute.

Comment: please provide the code snippet

Comment: If you need the enum to be stored as a string then include those attribute against the property in your class. Also, refer this  stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441290/json-serialization-of-enum-as-string

Answer (score 0):

You could try [TableEntity.Flatten](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tableentity.flatten?view=azure-dotnet) and [TableEntity.ConvertBack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tableentity.convertback?view=azure-dotnet). For what it's worth, especially if you call base.ReadEntity and base.WriteEntity, I don't think overriding Read and Write entity is an inelegant solution.