# best ptactice to customizing class property from string to enum?

Tags: c#, enums, properties

i will discuss my case to make a good understand for my question at first i am getting data from my api client as my class :

```
 return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestRespone>(responseContent);
```

so i get the data of my class :
which is

```
public enum TestStatus
{
   Sucess,
    Error
}
public class TestRespone
{
    public enum TestStatus{ get; set; }
    public string  Message { get; set; }
}
```

However i get the Teststatus from api as a string but i want to apply as an enum immediatly in my code :
i wrote extra code :

```
 public static TestStatus ToTestStatus(this string s)
        {
            switch (s)
            {
                case "INITIALIZED":
                    return SignatureStatus.Sucess;

                case "SIGNED":
                    return SignatureStatus.Error;
            }
         }
```

my question is how to custmize public enum TestStatus 
 to be immediatly an enum cause it alreay come as a sring ?
i mean i get it from api as string but i want it in class like enum

Comment: Something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/2441379/1971401 might work for your case.

Comment: @TimSchmelter thank you, seems I was a little hasty

Answer (score 0):

No directly you can't do it,
But if you must you should use [Custom Contract resolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ContractResolver.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to create something similar to what you want but the clutter is huge:

```
public enum TestStatus {
        Sucess,
        Error
            ///etc
    }
    public static class Ext {
    public static TestStatus ToTestStatus(this string target) {
        TestStatus testStatus;
        var enumerator = Enum.GetValues(typeof(TestStatus)).GetEnumerator();

        while (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
            if ((testStatus=((TestStatus)enumerator.Current)).ToString() == target) {
                return testStatus;
            }

        }
        return TestStatus.Error; //some default;

    }
}
```

Usage:

```
TestStatus c = "Error".ToTestStatus();
TestStatus d = "Success".ToTestStatus();
```

Refined it a bit :D