# ServiceStack Serializing enum values to a string other than the name

Tags: c#, serialization, servicestack

I need to serialize an enum's values to a string other than the name.

I tried doing this (see code below) but the attribute `[EnumMember(Value = "name")]` didn't change anything.  When I do `.ToJson()` I can see that the value is still "Monday" and not "MONDAY"

```
[DataContract]
public enum Day
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "MONDAY")]
    Monday,
    [EnumMember(Value = "TUESDAY")]
    Tuesday,
    [EnumMember(Value = "WEDNESDAY")]
    Wednesday,
    [EnumMember(Value = "THURSDAY")]
    Thursday,
    [EnumMember(Value = "FRIDAY")]
    Friday,
    [EnumMember(Value = "SATURDAY")]
    Saturday,
    [EnumMember(Value = "SUNDAY")]
    Sunday,
}
```

Comment: So you are trying JSON serialization? Please check out this [so post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441290/json-serialization-of-enum-as-string) which does seem to match your problem

Comment: I saw that post but that doesn't apply to me because ServiceStack is doing the serialization.  It's not a question of how to serialize it but rather how to get ServiceStack to do it the way I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just added support for `[EnumMember]` customization's in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/commit/bf2696f205e6e440d0e709f3ef8a4d637909ac2a) where your example will work as expected.

This change is available from v5.0.3 that's now [available on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget).