# JObject ToString with StringEnumConverter not working

Tags: c#, json.net

I am trying to serialize an anonymous class as follows:

```
public enum ErrorCode 
{
    A,
    B,
    C
}

var response = JObject.FromObject(new
{
    Error = new
    {
        Message = "Test",
        Code = ErrorCode.A
    }
})
.ToString(Formatting.None, new StringEnumConverter());
```

I expect `response` to be:

> {"Error":{"Message":"Test","Code":"A"}}

but I get:

> {"Error":{"Message":"Test","Code":0}}

I do get the correct response if I add `[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter)` attribute to the enum but I can't do that due to unrelated reasons.

You can find sample code [here](https://rextester.com/EIGRHX86120).

Am I missing something obvious here? My approach is similar to the example [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ToStringJsonConverter.htm)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2870420/10496806 

Try to create non-anonymous class and mark enum property with [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))] attribute

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you are applying `StringEnumConverter` too late in the process.  Json.NET converts the `enum` to a string or integer when your POCO is serialized to a `JObject` hierarchy, but you are supplying the converter later, when the `JObject` is finally formatted as a string.

Instead, supply the converter when serializing to `JObject` by using [`JObject.FromObject(Object, JsonSerializer)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_FromObject_1.htm) and constructing a serializer with the desired settings:

```
var response = JObject.FromObject(
    new
    {
        Error = new
        {
            Message = "Test",
            Code = ErrorCode.A
        }
    },
    JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(new JsonSerializerSettings { Converters = { new StringEnumConverter() } })
)
.ToString(Formatting.None);
```

Sample fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Y088XO).

(You might reasonably ask, when do the converters supplied to [`JToken.ToString(Formatting,JsonConverter[])`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToString_1.htm) ever matter?  While, *in general*, converters are applied during serialization to `JToken`, these converters are useful to control formatting of value types that Newtonsoft stores directly inside [`JValue.Value`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JValueValue.htm) without modification.  Most notably, `DateTime` values are stored directly in the `JToken` hierarchy without conversion during serialization.  This, in turn, happens because Newtonsoft recognizes `DateTime` values during tokenizing of a JSON stream by `JsonTextReader`, necessitating the ability to store the resulting `DateTime` objects inside a `JValue`.  For details see [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON) and [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_DateParseHandling.htm).  Conversely, as Json.NET does not try to recognize enum values during parsing, there was never a need to retain them in a `JToken` hierarchy.  Thus they're converted to strings or integers during the serialization phase.)

Comment: Life saver.. =D