# Deserialize Json string to Enum C#

Tags: c#, json, enums, deserialization

I am writing a test on a custom version of stringEnumConverter. But my test keeps throwing when I deserialize. I searched over stack overflow, but could not find what I did wrong. Following is a sample of what I'm doing:

```
namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    [Flags]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    enum TestEnum
    {
        none = 0, 
        obj1 = 1,
        obj2 = 2
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var jsonString = "{none}";
            var deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestEnum>(jsonString);
        }
    }
}
```

The exception I get on the deserialize line is Unexpected token StartObject when parsing enum.

I suspect it might be because I am representing the json string wrong, I also tried `"{\"none\"}", "{\"TestEnum\":\"none\"}", "{TestEnum:none}", "{none}" and "none"`.

Comment: `{none}` is not a valid json to begin with.

Comment: A valid json would be something like: `{test: none}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

{none} is not valid JSON, but 'none' is valid!

You should try the following:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        var jsonString = "'none'";
        var deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestEnum>(jsonString);
        Console.WriteLine(deserializedObject);
    }
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

If you serialize `TestEnum.none` into JSON, the result is `"none"`. A string is perfectly valid JSON.

Your JSON isn't even *valid* JSON:
* It is an object,
* containing key (but keys **must** be quoted with double quoted),
* that carries no value. (and an object key **must** have a value)

So... try something like this:

```
var jsonString = "\"none\"";
var deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestEnum>(jsonString);
```

But you shouldn't have to write a custom serializer. JSON.Net will do it for you. See

[.NET - JSON serialization of enum as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441290/net-json-serialization-of-enum-as-string)

But if you want to deserialize an object containing your enum, you'll want something along these lines:

```
{
  "enumKey" : "none"
}
```

Which would be something like this in your test:

```
var jsonString = "{ \"enumKey\" : \"none\" }";
```