# how to convert Enum definition to JavaScript object (json)

Tags: .net, jsonserializer

I also checked this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441290/javascriptserializer-json-serialization-of-enum-as-string) but it gives me same result.
enum definition:

```
    public enum myEnum
        {
            variable1 = 1,
            variable2 = 25,
            variable3 = 35
        }
```

Here's what I tried:

```
var myJsObject= @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Enum.GetValues(typeof(myEnum)), new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter()));
```

and this is what it returns:

```
["variable1","variable2","variable3"]
```

Expected result:

```
{"1":"variable1","25":"variable2","35":"variable3",}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can some thing like this..

```
   public enum myEnum
   {
      variable1 = 1,
      variable2 = 25,
      variable3 = 35
   }

    static Dictionary<int,string> EnumToDictionary<T>() where T : struct, IConvertible
    {
        if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("T must be an enum type");
        }
        var dictionary = Enum.GetValues(typeof(T))
            .Cast<T>()
            .ToDictionary( e=>  Convert.ToInt32(e), e => e.ToString());
        return dictionary;
    }
```

using...

```
var dictionary =  EnumToDictionary<tEnum>();
var jsonResult = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionary);
```