# Not able to serialize enum to string .net core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

using the below config in startup.cs
`services.AddControllers() .AddNewtonsoftJson(opt => opt.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter()))`

but not able to serialize the enum to string values. Only integer values are displayed in the swagger page. Could some please help me how to fix this?.

Comment: it's happening to me too with .net core 6

Answer (score 0):

You have several ways to achieve this.

- Add the `[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]` attribute on
  the Enum field.

  ```
  using Newtonsoft.Json;
  using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

  [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
  public Gender Gender { get; set; }
  ```
- Add `formatting` parameter during serialization.

  `string value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectlist,new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter());`

You can also refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2870420/12884742).