# Json Serializer - Serialize enum description instead of its value

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json

READ BEFORE MARK AS DUPLICATED

The "JavaScriptSerializer - JSON serialization of enum as string" question don't answer my question!

I'm trying to serialize an enum but I want the value of the enum present in its description attribute to be serialized and not its value

**Important to note that I don't want to use Newtonsoft**

Example

```
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

public class MyClassExample 
{
   [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
   public YesOrNo IsShipped { get;set; }
}

public enum YesOrNo  {
    [Description("Y")]
    Yes,
    [Description("N")]
    No
}
```

And I use like that:

```
var myJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new MyClassExample () { IsShipped = YesOrNo.Y });
```

The return is:

> { "IsShipped": "Yes" } but I expected { "IsShipped": "Y" }

And the same to

```
var myObject = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyClassExample>("{ ""IsShipped"": ""Y"" }");
```

How can I use the value o enums attribute to serialize/deserialize?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScriptSerializer - JSON serialization of enum as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441290/javascriptserializer-json-serialization-of-enum-as-string)

Comment: No, it doesn't solve. My problem is not being able to serialize to string, it is not being able to serialize and deserialize the value present in the enum attribute

Comment: Did you try to create own converter for it instead of `JsonStringEnumConverter`?

Comment: @RomanPatutin OP doesn't use `JavaScriptSerializer`

Comment: It doesn't look like you want to do what you want. You can not implement deserialization this way, because it goes thru the next code: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/0e0e852e83d5f30dfeeef7ac4999873ee10f9a4b/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/Converters/Value/EnumConverter.cs#L61 and you cannot override  Enum.TryParse.