# How to assign the Rigidbody2DbodyType by reading a saved string in a txt file?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am writing the bodyType of the assetsToSave gameObjects into the txt file which works perfectly

```
   assetBodyType[j] = assetsToSave[j].GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> 
 ().bodyType.ToString();
```

In my txt file there then is the string called "Kinematic" which i am parsing to

```
   assetBodyType[i] = data[0];
```

I dont need help on saving or loading because this works already.
My only problem is how i would assign the string "Kinematic" to the gameObject since it is a string ?

So my only problem is that i cant call the usual function like this

```
RigidbodyType2D.Kinematic
```

since i want to replace Kinematic with

```
  assetBodyType[j]
```

to have the actual bodyType and not everything to kinematic
how do i put this string into the function of Rigidbody2D.??
How else could i assign it ?

```
 possibleObjecs[j].GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().bodyType = 
 RigidbodyType2D.Kinematic;
```

I tried searching other methods but couldnt find anything

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Enum.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.parse?view=net-7.0) or [Enum.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.tryparse?source=recommendations&view=net-7.0) to parse a string to enum

```
possibleObjecs[j].GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().bodyType =
Enum.Parse(typeof(RigidbodyType2D), "Kinematic");
```

But i suggest a good way to do this is assign all the field that you want to save to a class and use a [Json converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to?pivots=dotnet-8-0) to save and load, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441290/javascriptserializer-json-serialization-of-enum-as-string) is a topic about convert json to enum in object.